# get points inside boxplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am creating a boxplot with matplotlib. How can I get the points inside the box ?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [2,4,5,62,57,3,8,3,96,2,34,43]

box=plt.boxplot(data)
```

Comment: Which points? To do what? Be more precise.

Comment: http://blog.contextures.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/boxplotsimple08.png see the image. Thank you

Comment: Doesn't really answer my questions.

Comment: Do you mean you want the values for the edges of the box?

Answer (score 1):

The *points inside the box* are the values that lie inside the interquartile range. The 1st and 3rd quartiles can be calculated with `np.quartile`, and once you know those values you can conditionally sample your data array:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([2,4,5,62,57,3,8,3,96,2,34,43])

box=plt.boxplot(data)

# Get all the data between the 1st and 3rd quartile
data_iqr = data[ (data >  np.percentile(data, 25)) & (data <  np.percentile(data, 75)) ]

# Visual confirmation:
plt.scatter(np.ones_like(data_iqr), data_iqr, marker='o', label='IQR')
plt.scatter(np.ones_like(data),     data,     marker='x', label='all')
plt.legend(frameon=False, loc='best')
```

[image]